# How do I get a status of IISreset - true if it is started and false if it is stopped

Tags: powershell

I am unable to get a `$true` or `$false` value returned for `IISStatus`

```
$status = iisreset /start
```

I want to check if IIS has been started or not.

Comment: List services/processes is an everyday thing in virtually any language. It's just a service. Use the ```Get-Sevice``` (to list all services and filter on status) or ```Get-Process``` (to get all processes and filter on running) cmdlets. You are using and cmd.exe executable, you need to explicitly trap for details you are after. All you are doing here is trying to send the full results of that command to the variable (btw, true or false is not what it returns), but you are not doing anything with the results you collected. That command returns 2 lines, so, ask from it that part you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment.

```
Get-Service -Name IISADMIN
# Results
<#
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  IISADMIN           IIS Admin Service
#>

iisreset /stop

# Results
<#
Attempting stop...

Internet services successfully stopped
#>



Get-Service -Name IISADMIN
# Results
<#
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Stopped  IISADMIN           IIS Admin Service 
#>

iisreset /start

# Results
<#
Attempting start...

Internet services successfully started
#>


Get-Service -Name IISADMIN
# Results
<#
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  IISADMIN           IIS Admin Service
#>



Stop-Service -Name IISADMIN
# Results
<#
WARNING: Waiting for service 'IIS Admin Service (IISADMIN)' to stop...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'IIS Admin Service (IISADMIN)' to stop...
#>

Get-Service -Name IISADMIN
# Results
<#
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Stopped  IISADMIN           IIS Admin Service 
#>

Start-Service -Name IISADMIN
Get-Service -Name IISADMIN
# Results
<#
Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  IISADMIN           IIS Admin Service 
#>

(Get-Service -Name IISADMIN).Status
# Results
<#
Running
#>
```

FYI, there re many IIS cmdlets to use, without having to revert back to executables.

```
Get-Command -Name 'IIS*'
```

They are part of the 'IISAdministration' module.

```
Find-Module -Name 'IIS*'

Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                                                       
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                                       
1.1.0.0              IISAdministration                   PSGallery            IIS Configuration management module
```

Answer (score 1):

Check automatic variable - either

[`$LASTEXITCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#lastexitcode) - *Contains the exit code of the last Windows-based program that was run.*

or

[`$?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#section-1) - *Contains the execution status of the last command. It contains `True` if the last command succeeded and `False` if it failed.*

having in mind the following relation (the same source):

> For native commands (executables), `$?` is set to `True` when
> `$LASTEXITCODE` is `0`, and set to `False` when `$LASTEXITCODE` is any
> other value.

**Example 1**:

```
$status = iisreset /start
"$? $LASTEXITCODE"
$status
```

> ```
> False 5
>
> Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to use this 
> command. Either have your account added to the administrator local group of 
> the remote computer or to the domain administrator global group.
> ```

**Example 2** (elevated PowerShell):

```
$status = iisreset /start
"$? $LASTEXITCODE"
$status
```

> ```
> True 0
>
> Attempting start...
> Internet services successfully started
> ```